# What does bit rate do?

Tags: java, audio, video, xuggler, rate

I want to make a video transcoder as a holiday project in Java. I was looking into the basics of video files and came across terms like containers, bit rate, bit depth and so on.

I have questions regarding bitrate.

I know bitrate is the amount of data that is contained in the video per second. Sound also has a bit rate but is considerably lower than that of video, obviously.

So, say there is  a video that is of 8 Mbps (YouTube HD 720p) and the user wants to transcode it to a lower bitrate of 4 Mbps.
**Will this cause the sound to go out of sync?**

I am not doing the transcoding myself, I am using `Xuggler` for it which contains a lot of codecs like `H264` and others.

**Also, if, by an accident the user decides to convert a 4 Mbps video to a 8 Mbps video, what will happen ?**
This situation is possible if the user gives a video captured from a phone camera and decides to store it in DVD quality.

Also, there are other things to take into consideration like frame rate right ? Because a low capacity device can not handle a higher frame rate. **is frame rate related to bit rate?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities of what will happen, depending on the decoder and so on. I'm not familiar with Xuggler, but:

The sound should not go out of sync if you drop video bitrate with a proper software. It will not shorten the video or anything like that. Depending on what you do to it, either the frame-rate will drop ( it will discard every 2nd frame) or each frame will be more compressed.

Comment: `Depending on what you do to it, either the frame-rate will drop` so if I drop the bit rate, the frame rate may drop automatically?

Comment: It's up to the software really. Most software will let you filter/pack/change encoding etc to the video. Bitrate is not the one usually being changed, but more the result. If you drop framerate, bitrate drops. If you lower resolution, bitrate drops.

Comment: So, say I need to convert a video so that I can play it on a low-capacity Android device. I will need to change the `bit rate` (the data needed to be processed per frame) and the `frame rate` (the rate at which the video will be displayed) and the `resolution` (how big the frame will be)` right ?

Comment: or just `bit rate` and `resolution` ?

Comment: Well if you want to make a "lite" video. I would drop the resolution to max 720p if you want to keep "HD". Drop framerate to around 20, maybe bit lower. Less powerfull devices could work better with 480p resolution. Also the encoding of the video matters, if its packed hard to a small file, it requires more CPU to play.

Comment: OK so for optimization, I must change both the bit rate **and** frame rate ? There is a chart here: http://gizmodo.com/5048025/giz-explains-why-hd-video-downloads-arent-very-high-def

Comment: MUST is not the right word. But less frames per second automatically means less bits per second. I would first try with changing resolution and framerate and see what that does to the bitrate. If your software offers a option of dropping framerate from 8 to 4, try that. Considering there are such a wide variety of devices, you need to try out different options to get optimal performance/look ratio.

Comment: I knwo book recommendation are frowned upon but is there a good book you would recommend for digital media processing ?

Comment: No sorry, don't know any good books. learned my "knowledge" in school.

Answer (score 1):

The audio and video are generally independent, so changing the bitrate of one will *not* affect the other. In the case of changing to a higher bitrate, the transcoder will either throw an error, or produce a larger file at the same quality as the original.

The frame rate is not directly related. The bit rate is just a measure of how many bits are being used to encode one second of audio or video.